# how to make Filepond image draggable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, filepond

I will make FilePond images draggable inside preview area the images position can be change with each others some can help out how to do that?

check screenshot
https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5QEP.jpg

```
<div id="main">
  <div id="header">
    <h1>Drag and drop fileupload</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <form class="dropzone" id="fileupload"></form>
  </div>

</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $(".dz-image").draggable();
  });
</script>
<script src="./dropzone.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
  $("#fileupload").dropzone({
    url: "upload"
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the custom scripts and set the `allowReorder` to `true`.

```js
FilePond.create({
  allowReorder: true
})
```